# Get Store View info in JS

Tags: store-view, javascript

Is it possible to get the current store view data in a js file. I mean is that info is stored somewhere in the js environment?

Comment: What info from the store would you need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No they are not as far as I know. You could make it available by creating a variable in templates/page/html/head.phtml like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var MAGE_STORE_ID = '<?php echo Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();?>';
//]]>
</script>
```

This would give you the ability to call "MAGE_STORE_ID" in your javascript that provides the current store id.